# <object> and link in included SVG document

Tags: html, object, hyperlink, svg

I'm including a SVG document with a object tag in a webpage.

```
<html>
    <head>
         <title>CA/7GroupPDZBP2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <object data=".\toto.svg" height="400" src=".\toto.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="100%"></object>
    <body>
</html>
```

In my toto.svg document i have some links like this :

```
<svg style="background-color:transparent;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1925 476" width="1925" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <a style="cursor:pointer;" xlink:href="page2.html">
        <text>Tony</text>
    </a>
</svg>
```

However if i click on the link, only the content of the object tag is replaced by the destination link in my page. The whole page is not refreshing.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem ?

Thanks for your help,
Cuva

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify target="_top" on the link according to http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#Links